# Cannot implicitly cast type - .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a kafka class that returns a List of Lists but when I go, I have problems starting it.

```
public IList<IList<SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas.historicalDataMeasurementInfo>> equipments
{
    get
    {
        return this._equipments;
    }
    set
    {
        this._equipments = value;
    }
}
```

to initialize it, I use

```
response.historicalDataMeasurement.equipments = new  List<List<historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>();
```

but I get the following error

It is not possible to implicitly cast type "System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas.historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>" to "System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList <SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas.historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>". Is there an explicit cast (is there a missing cast?)

soon I get a null instance when I try to perform:

```
response.historicalDataMeasurement.equipments.Add(historicalDataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it using:

```
response.historicalDataMeasurement.equipments = new  List<IList<historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>()
```

Note that it's a `List` of `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change IList to IEnumerable as below then also you will be able to create object.

```
public IEnumerable<IList<SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas.historicalDataMeasurementInfo>> equipments
{
    get
    {
        return this._equipments;
    }
    set
    {
        this._equipments = value;
    }
}
```

To initialize it:

```
response.historicalDataMeasurement.equipments = new  List<List<historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your trouble is because you need to cast the item type within a list.
To do so you can use the LINQ extensions.

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

yourList
    .Cast<IList<SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas.historicalDataMeasurementInfo>>()
    .ToList();
```

The call to `Cast<T>` changes your list to an `IEnumerable<T>` which is why the call to `ToList()` is required to change it back to a list.